How to type annotate the splat/spread function
Consider the common splat function, also known as spread, which takes a function of n arguments and wraps it in a function of one n-element tuple argument:
def splat(f: Callable[???, A]) -> Callable[[???], A]:
    def splatted(args: ???) -> A:
        return f(*args)
    return splatted

How do I annotate the type of parameter f and the return value? Is it even expressible in Python's type system?

Use generic types. The type of f is Callable. The return type is the same as the return type of f.

Also, don't use a decorator for this.

@kindall This is not intended to be used a decorator, but as a utility function for parser combinators (e.g. https://parsita.drhagen.com/utility_functions/)

I don't think the linked duplicate addresses the heart of this question, which is how to "convert" from a single tuple to an arbitrary number of arguments. f's type can accurately be captured with Callable[P, A] (where P is a ParamSpec), but it's not obvious how, if even possible, to specify the related return type of splat in terms of P.args.

@chepner Yeah, this is definitely not a dup, but someone used the dup hammer on it, so I guess it's gone.

I forgot that dupe hammer works to reopen questions as well...

Sorry, I hammered it because even though it's might not be intended to be used as a decorator, it seems like it works similarly so the type hints woud be the same.

Strongly related, possibly duplicate: Type hinting a higher order function that takes in a function and return a new function whose arguments are that of the original, but repeated twice.

Sure this is possible, but I'd advise sticking to positional-only parameters and strictly avoid keyword parameters (which won't work).
The idea is to employ a type variable tuple (TVT) to capture the function's n (positional) parameters, then unpack the parameters (represented by the TVT) into a single concrete tuple in the transformed function. The transformed function will then only have one parameter, which is the concrete tuple.
Demo (mypy Playground, Pyright playground):
import collections.abc as cx

class A: ...

def splat[*Ts](f: cx.Callable[[*Ts], A], /) -> cx.Callable[[tuple[*Ts]], A]:
    def splatted(args: tuple[*Ts], /) -> A:
        return f(*args)
    return splatted


@splat
def f(a: int, b: str, /) -> A:
    return A()

>>> f((1, ""))  # OK
>>> f(1, "")  # error, expected 1 tuple argument
>>> f((1, 1))  # error, second element of tuple should be `str`

The decorator usage is for demonstration purposes only - you don't need to use this as a decorator.

I had to set enable_incomplete_feature = "NewGenericSyntax" in my config file, but this absolutely worked.

@drhagen oh, I didn't mention that, because the question didn't say you were specifically using mypy. You don't need to add that configuration option from the next version of mypy onwards, which should be released next week.
